# How to diff PDF files?

Tags: pdf, diff, binaryfiles

Sometimes, when I download a PDF file, such as one of my statements from my bank's website, and then, at a later time, download the same file again, both files differ.

How can I see how they differ?

I've tried:

```
diff file-1.pdf file-2.pdf
```

But that just prints:

```
Binary files file-1.pdf and file-2.pdf differ
```

Comment: Have you looked at PDF-specific command-line tools, like XPDF? (https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftotext-man.html)

Comment: @ZachYoung no, I haven't. Thanks for sharing. :-) Xpdf looks very useful.

Comment: I wrote up an answer with `pdftotext` a while a back https://askubuntu.com/a/914169

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
diff -a file-1.pdf file-2.pdf | less
```

Or:

```
git diff -a file-1.pdf file-2.pdf
```

Example of `diff`'s output:

> ```
> 1869,1870c1869,1870
> < /CreationDate (D:20220504152530-00'00')
> < /ModDate (D:20220504152530-00'00')
> ---
> > /CreationDate (D:20220509154833-00'00')
> > /ModDate (D:20220509154833-00'00')
> ```

Notes:

- For either `diff` or `git-diff`, the `-a`, `--text` option "treat[s] all files as text". (See `man diff` or `man git-diff`.)
- I use `less` in case `diff -a` outputs any binary data. (See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1520750/59284) and [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73713/41467#comment107122_73713).)
- You must add the `--no-index` option after `git diff -a` when you run the command in a working tree controlled by Git and both files are inside that working tree. (See `man git-diff`.)
- To view a PDF file's data as text, do `less file.pdf`.

Comment: What kind of results are you getting? I'd imagine it'd be very hard to discern from diff what's actually changed.

Comment: @ZachYoung I added an an example of `diff`'s output to my answer. Yeah, it probably would for very different PDF files, such as those generated from different bank statement data, but I'm just diffing very similar PDF files, such as those generated from the same bank statement data but at different times.

Comment: Please be aware that the PDFs must not merely be similar in appearance in a viewer, they must internally be similar. Thus, for a use case as yours - *download a PDF file, such as one of my statements from my bank's website, and then, at a later time, download the same file again* - tweaking diff may result in something sensible. But consider a use case like having such a bank statement downloaded from your bank and comparing it to the same file opened in Adobe Acrobat with a single digit changed and then saved anew: Here you will hardly find a single non-trivial line without changes.